# Setting equal box height by taking parent container height & applying it to child elements

Tags: jquery

I am trying to take the parent container height and then apply it to the child containers within, with an end-result to be responsive on window resize, and disable the function for below window size 768px

Please see jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8vks5ubj/9/embedded/result/

```
jQuery('.common-height').each(function(){

var highestBox = 0;
jQuery('.center', this).each(function(){

    if($(this).outerHeight() > highestBox) 
       highestBox = jQuery(this).outerHeight(); 
}); 

jQuery('.center',this).outerHeight(highestBox);

});
```

Would really appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function setHeight() {
    var arr = [],
        $elems = $('.someblock'); // Place there your divs

    $elems.each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).outerHeight()); // Divs height moved to array
    });

    $elems.css('height', Math.max.apply(0, arr)); //Find max value and apply css height
};

($(window).width() < 768) && setHeight(); 
//When document loaded and window width less than 768px -> call function

$(window).resize(function(){
    ($(window).width() < 768) && setHeight();
});
```

Watch in action: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4yxLx21d/1/) (just resize window with divs)

P.S. Sorry for my English ;)